# useeffect infinite loop even though state data is not changing

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-state

My program goes into an infinite loop constantly calling useEffect() everytime I start the app. I have one state that I don't think is changing other than in the retrieveItemStatus() function so I'm confused on why its going into a loop like it is.

```
const App = () => {
  var items;
  const [itemStatuses, updateStatuses] = useState({});

  const retrieveItemStatus = async () => {
    var tempStatuses;
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@item_Statuses");
      if (value !== null) {
        tempStatuses = await JSON.parse(value);
        //console.log("123456");
      } else {
        tempStatuses = await JSON.parse(
          JSON.stringify(require("../default-statuses.json"))
        );
      }
      updateStatuses(tempStatuses);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  retrieveItemStatus();

  useEffect(() => {
    const copyData = async () => {
      const itemsCopy = [];

      const coll = await collection(db, "Items");
      const querySnapshots = await getDocs(coll);
      const docsArr = querySnapshots.docs;
      docsArr.map((doc) => {
        var data = doc.data();
        if (itemStatuses[data.name] === "locked") return;
        itemsCopy.push(data);
      });
      items = itemsCopy;
      //getItems([...itemsCopy]);
    };

    copyData();

  }, [itemStatuses]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>temp.......</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: What does the `getItems` do?

Comment: oops that was supposed to commented out. fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `useEffect`. You're calling `retrieveItemStatus` **unconditionally** every time your component function is called to render the componennt. `retrieveItemStatus` calls `updateStatuses` which **changes state**. You see your `useEffect` callback get run repeatedly as a side-effect of that, because your `useEffect` callback has `itemStatuses` as a dependency.

I assume you only need the `itemStatuses` to get fetched once. If so, put the call in a `useEffect` callback with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(retrieveItemStatus, []);
```

Also, you have (note the `***`):

```
const App = () => {
  var items // ***
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    const copyData = async () => {
      // ...

      items = itemsCopy; // ***

      // ...
    };

    copyData();

  }, [itemStatuses]);
};
```

That won't work, by the time you assign to `items` from the callback, anything you might have been trying to do with `items` will already have just used `undefined` (the value it gets when you don't give it one). If you need `items` to be retained, either put it in state (if you use it for rendering) or in a ref (if you don't).

---

In a comment you said:

> Ok so I put `retrieveItemStatus()` call inside `useEffect` and removed the dependency which fixed the looping. But now there is an issue where `itemStatuses` state doesn't get updated before `copyData()` is called and `itemStatuses` is needed.. so it doesn't do anything until I manually refresh/render the whole thing again.

If `copyData` relies on the result from `retrieveItemStatus`, then put the calls to each of them in the *same* `useEffect`, not calling `copyData` until you get the results from `retrieveItemStatus`. Something along the lines of the below, though you'll need to tweak it of course as I don't have all the details (I've also made some other comments and changes in there I've flagged up):

```
// *** There's no need to recreate this function on every render, just
// have it return the information
const retrieveItemStatus = async () => {
    try {
        let tempStatuses; // *** Declare variables in the innermost scope you can
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@item_Statuses");
        if (value !== null) {
            tempStatuses = await JSON.parse(value);
            //console.log("123456");
        } else {
            // *** stringify + parse isn't a good way to copy an object,
            // see your options at:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/
            tempStatuses = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require("../default-statuses.json")));
        }
        return tempStatuses;
    } catch (error) {
        // *** Not even a `console.error` to tell you something went wrong?
    }
};

// *** Similarly, just pass `itemStatuses` into this function
const copyData = async (itemStatuses) => {
    const coll = await collection(db, "Items");
    const querySnapshots = await getDocs(coll);
    const docsArr = querySnapshots.docs;
    // *** Your previous code was using `map` just as a loop,
    // throwing away the array it creates. That's an anti-
    // pattern, see my post here:
    // https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/
    // Instead, let's just use a loop:
    // (Alternatively, you could use `filter` to filter out
    // the locked items, and then `map` to build `itemsCopy`,
    // but that loops through twice rather than just once.)
    const itemsCopy = [];   // *** I moved this closer to where
                            // it's actually filled in
    for (const doc of docsArr) {
        const data = doc.data();
        if (itemStatuses[data.name] !== "locked") {
            itemsCopy.push(data);
        }
    }
    //getItems([...itemsCopy]); // *** ?
    return itemsCopy;
};

const App = () => {
    // *** A new `items` is created on each render, you can't just
    // assign to it. You have to make it a member of state (or use
    // a ref if it's not used for rendering.)
    const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
    const [itemStatuses, setItemStatuses] = useState({});
    // ***               ^−−−−− the standard convention is `setXyz`.
    // You don't have to follow convention, but it makes it easier
    // for other people to read and maintain your code if you do.

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const newStatuses = await retrieveItemStatus();
            const newItems = await copyData(newStatuses);
            // *** Do you need `itemStatuses` to be in state at all? If it's
            // only used for calling `copyData`, there's no need.
            setItemStatuses(newStatuses);
            setItems(newItems);
        })().catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }, []);

    // *** You didn't show what you're using here, so it's hard to be
    // sure what needs to be in state and what doesn't.
    // Only put `items` or `itemStatuses` in state if you use them for
    // rendering.
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>temp.......</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Here are those links as links:

- [*What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/)
- [*Misusing `map`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/) (on my blog)

Comment: Ok so I put retrieveItemStatus() call inside useEffect and removed the dependency which fixed the looping. But now there is an issue where itemStatuses state doesn't get updated before copyData() is called and itemStatuses is needed.. so it doesn't do anything until I manually refresh/render the whole thing again.

Comment: @skushu - If there's a dependency between the two, do them in the same `useEffect` callback, waiting until `retrieveItemStatus` completes before calling `copyData`. I've updated the answer to show doing that and to flag up a few other issues I saw.

Answer (score 2):

@T.J. Crowder's answer is correct but I want to clarify a small point, so you understand why your useEffect didn't stop running.

As you you know, when the dependency in dependency array changes, useEffect runs. But the data in your itemStatuses doesn't change right(according to you)? So why does useEffect re-runs? Let's look at the below example:

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {};
const obj3 = {a:2};
const obj4 = {a:2};


console.log(obj1 === obj2)
console.log(obj3 === obj4)

console.log(obj3.a === obj4.a)
```

As you can see javascript doesn't think that an empty object is strictly equal to another empty object. It is because these objects refer to the different locations in memory regardless of their content.

So that's why every time retrieveItemStatus ran, it updated itemStatuses. Then because itemStatuses got updated(although the value is same), useEffect triggered a re-render, so again everything started all over.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason is in calling `retrieveItemStatus();` without any event.
If you want to call this function when page loading, you should like this.

```
...
useEffect(() => {
  retrieveItemStatus()
}, [])
...
```

This will fix loop issue.